# How can We attach excel file and send a Notification mail in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

How can We attach excel file and send a Notification mail in Sharepoint Online

•   Attachment to be available only for FILING Team.
•   Once the filing done, filing team will attach excel file.
•   The excel file should be attached and deliver to REQUESTOR and the APPROVER in final Notification mail, (Auto generated mail via tool) once filing done.

Answer (score 1):

I don' exactly understand, what you want to do as "attach excel file and send a notification" but you should use SharePoint Document library and SharePoint Workflow or Flow.

- Create SharePoint Document library
- Set permissions for Filing team
- Create workflow on this library
- Create task for filing team and if somebody will finish this task it will continue
- Use Impersonation step for Replacing item permissions, set permissions for requestor (http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html)
- Create task for Requestor, after finishing, set permissions for Approver and create task for approver

Each task can create email notification.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to send emails with attachments using OOB SharePoint Designer Workflow actions.

We can use flow to send notification email with attachment. We can select one flow about the notification email in the document library or list. In the flow, we can add attachment in the email action.

We also can download and use free Office API to send notification email with attachment. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Send Email With Attachment In Office 365 (SharePoint Online).](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/send-email-with-attachment-in-office-365-sharepoint-online/)